# Local variables vs instance variables

Tags: c#, .net, optimization, instance, local

I've been doing a lot of research on C# optimization for a game that I'm building with XNA, and I still don't quite understand whether local variables are instance variables give better performance when constantly being updated and used.

According to http://www.dotnetperls.com/optimization , you should avoid parameters and local variables, meaning instance variables are the best option in terms of performance.

But a while ago, I read on another StackOverflow post (I can't seem to find where it was) that local variables are stored in a part of memory that is far quicker to access, and that every time an instance variable is set, the previous value has to be erased as a tedious extra step before a new value can be assigned.

I know that design-wise, it might break encapsulation to use instance variables in that kind of situation, but I'm strictly curious about performance. Currently in my game, I pass around local variables to 3 out of 7 methods in a class, but I could easily promote the variables to instance variables and be able to entirely avoid parameter passing and local variables.

So which would be better?

Comment: *is your program running slow?* If you should avoid parameters and local variables you should probably avoid c# at all, since you will write an unreadable program. Such 'optimization' typically has no effect on the performance. Usually there is more evident performance pitfall elsewhere.

Comment: Do you have any measurable performance issues? Can your profile your code to see if the issue is coming from micro optimization like this or from bigger issues? (Or is this just a curiosity question :))

Comment: I also heavily doubt that accessing local variables or instace variables are *any* kind of bottleneck in *any* .Net application...

Comment: I think the OP is asking a general theoretical question rather than guidance. I do not think he plans to optimise by avoiding passing arguments at all.

Comment: Wouldn't promoting arguments to fields stop the optimizing from putting them in registers?

Comment: Actually yeah, it's a bit more of a theoretical question. I'm also wondering if I should use the more performance-capable solution as a best practice to take forward into any code I write. But as harold mentioned, would promoting arguments to fields prevent them from being stored in the registers? And if so, is that faster than having instance variables that are instantiated once?

Comment: The conclusion "meaning instance variables are the best option in terms of performance" you draw from "According to http://www.dotnetperls.com/optimization , you should avoid parameters and local variables" is incorrect. While passing arguments and declaring local variables take time, accessing arguments or local variables is faster than accessing fields. See http://www.dotnetperls.com/local-variable-field-optimization

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I wouldn't be looking at this as the culprit for performance issues (unless you are constantly passing large `struct`s). My naive understanding is that GC pressure is the usual consideration with XNA games, so being frugal with your object instances basically.

If the variable is method-local, the value itself or the reference (when a reference type) will be located on the stack. If you promote those to class member variables they will be located in the class's memory on the heap.

Method calls would technically become faster as you are no longer copying references or values on the call (because presumably you can remove the parameters from the method if the method is also local to the class).

I'm not sure about the relative performance, but to me it seems that if you need to persist the value then the value makes some sense being in the class...

To me it seems like any potential gains from doing one in favour of the other is outweighed by the subtle differences between the two - making them roughly equivalent or so small a difference as to not care.

Of course, all this stands to be corrected in the face of hard numbers from performance profiling.

Comment: Good points. I'm just curious as to what might be a good rule-of-thumb to follow when deciding between instance variables and local variables  when writing fresh code with performance in mind (or, if anything, just to know what's theoretically faster out of curiosity :)).

Answer (score 2):

Are your variables reference (class, or string) or value (struct) types?

For reference types there's no meaningful difference between passing them as a method argument and holding them on an object instance. In the first case when entering the function the argument will (for functions with a small argument count) end up in a register. In the second case the reference exists as an offset of the data pointed to in memory by 'this'. Either scenario is a quick grab of a memory address and then fetching the associated data out of memory (this is the expensive part).

For value types the above is true for *certain* types (integers or floats that can fit in your CPU's registers). For those specific things it's probably a little cheaper to pass-by-value vs. extracting them off 'this'. For other value types (DateTime or structs you might make yourself or any struct with multiple members) when the data is going to be too large to pass in through a register so this no longer matters.

It's pretty unlikely, though, that any of this matters for the performance of your application (even a game). Most common .NET performance problems (that are not simply inefficient algorithms) are going to, in some form, come from garbage generation. This can manifest itself through accidental boxing, poor use of string building, or poor object lifetime management (your objects have lifespans that are neither very short nor very long/permanent).

Comment: My variables are XNA Vector2 structs (containing two floats). Ahh so if the data are value-types and can fit in the registers, then it's slightly faster to use them as local variables? Does that contradict with the link I posted with the questions (under "Avoid Local Variables): "When you call a method in your C# program, the runtime allocates a separate memory region to store all the local variable slots. This memory is allocated on the stack even if you do not access the variables in the function call." Does it actually allocate to the stack or to the registers?

Comment: Or are stacks and registers the same thing? I know the heap is different, but I'm not sure about that.

Answer (score 1):

Not passing arguments will be slightly faster, not initialising local objects (if they are objects) will be faster.

What you read in both articles is not contradictory, one is mentioning that passing argument costs time and the other mention that initialising objects (in local objects) can cost time as well.

About allocating new objects, one thing you can do is to reuse objects rather discarding them. For example, some time ago, I had to write some code for traders which would compute the price of a few products in real time in C/C++ and C#. I obtained a major boost of performance by not re-creating the system of equation from scratch but only by merely updating the system incrementally from the previous system.

This avoided allocating memory for the new objects, initialising new objects and often the system would be nearly the same so I would have only to modify tiny bits to update it.

Usually, before to do any optimisation you want to make sure that you are optimising something that will impact significantly the overall performance ?

Comment: Ahh interesting. My main goal is more to try to develop a rule-of-thumb for what I should lean towards when I'm writing fresh code rather than optimizing. So would you say in 90%-99% of cases, using instance variables is faster than local variables?