# Is it better to make a local scope variable a class variable if it is being used in an update/listener to avoid it being created every time?

Tags: c#, heap-memory, stack-memory

Consider the following snippet, where you can get a float (or the corresponding type) from the `MyType` instance argument:

```
void myMethod(MyType floatArgument) {
    float myFloat = (float)MyType.Value;
    if (myFloat < 100) {
        //not meaningfull code
    }
}
```

If the method is being continiusly called in a listener, or an Update of a physics or graphics engine, is it strictly better regarding efficiency to make it a class variable like this?? :

```
private float myFloat
void myMethod(MyType floatArgument) {
    myFloat = (float)MyType.Value;
    if (myFloat < 100) {
            //not meaningfull code
    }
}
```

The variable is used only in local scope, so AFAIK it would be created in the stack every time. So it would be faster to make a class variable from it, so that even the memory for that variable would be on the heap and the memory consumption would be higher, the code would run faster.

I know that for a float might not be a big deal, but take it as it if would be lots of variables or an instance of a large data class.

Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: Try setup a test with BenchmarkDotNet, so you can see if there is any significative performance and memory usage difference .

Comment: apart from "just try it" which is a valid advice, I am asking for the concept of how c# operates

Comment: Is myMethod invoked from a single thread, or multiple?

Comment: Unity gameEngine. Single thread

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Local variables vs instance variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11684289/local-variables-vs-instance-variables)

Comment: thanks, the read was very useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tinoz said its more of a design design, there is technically a difference in performance but its insignificant. Having it in class scope will use memory to store it even when the variable isn't in use, where as having it in the methods scope will use slightly more CPU time to create it each time the method is run.

You could try to measure the difference but in reality its such a small amount that unless your calling the function thousands of times a second or having thousands of instances, it won't make much difference. Even then, the difference may still be pretty marginal. As an example, having a int in the class scope in C# only takes 4 bytes or 0.000004 MB roughly, couldn't say how much execution time defining the same int variable would take though.

It's insignificant enough that having the variable local to the method for tidier code outweighs the performance cost either way, but it does come down to the design of your application.

Edit: The thought occurs this may matter more when defining new instances of larger objects in some large scale applications. This would likely have a greater affect on performance depending on what the object has stored. Its still unlikely to matter a huge amount unless you have huge objects store vast amounts of data in which case you should check the design of your application to see if such a object needs to store that much data.

In this event, it comes down to memory usage vs CPU time. As mentioned before, storing variables in class scope will use memory all the time to store the data. In method scope would still use the same amount of memory but only whilst the method runs and would be cleared after. It would take more CPU cycles though to complete as your defining the variables each time.

For the sake of argument, lets say the memory usage and CPU time used for this is a significant amount. It becomes a balancing game of speed versus memory. If your trying to optimise for systems with less memory or similar reasoning, then defining in method scope for all methods saves memory cost though would increase execution time. If you want the task to be completed quicker and memory usage is a lower priority, then defining in class scope for all variables will use more memory as your storing more data for longer, but would decrease the execution time required.

It's still unlikely to matter either way as in most cases we are talking minute amounts of time and memory, but in rare cases where it does matter it would be best to consider the design of your application and what your trying to optimise best for

Comment: thanks for your answer. Up to what I researched it seems that if you need to persist the value then the value makes some sense being in the class according to my reasoning and your answer, which more less indicates its correct. However local vs class variable are roughly equivalent or so small a difference so as to not care of performance. Meaning that the reasoning of the question is technically right but the difference is negligible is be cared of.

Comment: It seems also that the fact of local vs class variable is not relevant no matter how big the app is, or how frequent the call to the variable is. Meaning that even from a game developer mindset (game update runs 60 times per second, so once efficiency needs arise every corner to cut  is relevant), the difference is negligible so as to consider both scenarios the same

Comment: Effectively, yes. The performance difference is so small as to not really matter. Its more a matter of if you want to store the variable for a longer period of time and having tidier code that easier to read and maintain. Even in terms of game optimisation it makes very little difference.

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion, it's a design decision. But mostly, you can simply create a local scope variable. Why? That's per design, if you call your method very, very, VERY often and rapidly, THEN you can get in trouble with your memory. On the other Hand, when you move it into class scope, everytime you create your class you will adress memory for your variable which can be never used. So, it's up to you and your design. Even performance, if you have an object, there is nearly NO performance issue rather than reserving a bit of memory for holding it because your object is set as reference.

For the sake of cleaner code, i would recommend using local scope in those cases.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I think I wont get in trouble with memory because the garbage collection takes care of the stack, so If I dont make a `new` I think I should be fine. On the  other hand regarding the "there is nearly NO performance issue", the core of the question is if there is a performance difference or not, regarding the reasoning exposed and how c# operates, not how big the performance issue can be to support the code change design of making a local variable a class variable

Comment: a bit lat, but: Keep in mind. Even with a `new` and a very huge object created in your method. you simply shift the CPU usage from point A to point B... you WILL have to take the time to fill your data.... it is by design and your decision WHEN you will do it. You can't really save the cpu time